# How to use MIM SP1 to sync Oracle DB data into SharePoint UPS application?

Tags: 2016, ups, mim

I have configured MIM SP1 with SharePoint 2016 and sync working from AD to User Profile Application.

Now I have users data into Oracle database and AD & Oracle having user's email id common, so I want MIM also sync Oracle db so that users remaining information should also show in User Profile Application.

Please guide.